# I want to use mathematica so solve a system of 3 diferential equations but it is giving some errors

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to solve this system of eqs

```
dw(v,t)/dt =2g(v,t) w(t,v)

g(t,v)= Pi/2 (v^2)d g0(v,t)/dt

d go(v,t)/dt + d/dv[dw/dt *1/v^3)]=0
```

initial conditions

```
f0= (a/(Pi)^0.5)*e^[v^2/ve^2] + (b/(Pi)^0.5)*e^[(v - u)^2/ve^2]

a^2 + b^2 = 1

f0=go(v,0)

w(v,0)=0
```

This is my code

Here I am initializing some variables and defining f0 that is g(v,t=0).

```
a = 0.5;

b = (3^0.5)/2;

ve = 1;

u = 1;

f0[v_] = (a/(Pi)^0.5)Exp[v^2/ve^2] + (b/(Pi)^0.5)Exp[(v - u)^2/ve^2];

u1 = Log[((1 - a^2)/a^2)^0.5]/(2*u) + u/2;

u2 = 3u/2 - Log[((1 - a^2)/a^2)^0.5]/(2u);

f0[u1]

f0[u2]
```

Here I am using a system of 3 eqs for 3 functions and equating g(v,0)=f0

```
sol = NDSolve[{

D[go[v, t], t] + D[D[w[v, t], t], v]/(v^3) + (-3v^(-4))D[w[v, t], t] == 0,

g[v, t] == Pi/2 (v^2) D[go[v, t], v],

go[v, 0] == f0[v],

D[w[v, t], t] == 2g[v, t]w[v, t],

w[v, 0] == 0},

{go[v, t], W[v, t]},

{v, u1, u2},

{t, 0, 10000000000}]
```

And it is returning errors like

> The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. 
> Adding artificial diffusion may help

> "No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for 
> {g}; the result may not be unique"

> The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. 
> Adding artificial diffusion may help.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I reckon the problematic syntax is `D[go[v, t], t]` and `D[w[v, t], t]` because `t` is being used in two senses.

Comment: Please ask https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/